# Is there a bounded-time algorithm for Envy-free cake-cutting?

Tags: algorithms

I am engineering student,i have doubts regarding the topic can anyone help me to find solution.

Comment: We expect you to do some research on your own before asking here. So, what did you try? What are your own thoughts on the question?

Comment: This is answered in the obvious place on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envy-free_cake-cutting.  We don't want questions that can be answered simply by looking in the obvious place on Wikipedia (or other standard resources).  Instead, you should do thorough research before asking.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 4):

A bounded-time algorithm for the problem has been presented by Haris Aziz and Simon Mackenzie (*A Discrete and Bounded Envy-Free Cake Cutting Protocol for Any Number of Agents*, [arXiv:1604.03655](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03655), April 2016).